# How do I reference variables in the WHERE portion of an SQL clause for bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I found this code [here](https://github.com/Flowminder/COVID-19/blob/master/indicators_1_2.sql)... besides syntax problems (a missing comma, using functions as fields, at least...), it gives me an error in Google BigQuery with the "date" in the `WHERE` clause. Not sure if this is an error in BQ or just not possible to "guess" date yet...

```
CREATE TABLE count_unique_subscribers_per_region_per_day AS (
    SELECT date(calls.datetime) AS date,
        cells.region AS region
        COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn) AS count
    FROM calls
    INNER JOIN cells
        ON calls.location_id = cells.cell_id
    WHERE date >= '2020-02-01'
          AND date <= CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY 1, 2

);
```

How do you reference `date` in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: what is the error exactly? It appears as though there is additional schema that must precede this table creation (Calls table, Cells table)

Comment: @BryanOfEarth:  Unrecognized name: date at [8:5]

Comment: 1) BigQuery seems to have issues with aliases. 2) What makes you think this SQL is meant for BigQuery? It looks more like MySQL to me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6a5992

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the schema for the tables in this project (https://github.com/Flowminder/COVID-19/blob/master/core_tables.sql), you will see that the table `calls` has a column called `date`. A query like the one in the question will work, as long as the table `calls` has a column `date`.

If the error you see says `Unrecognized name: date at`, then your table `calls` might not have a column `date`.

As you can see here, the query in the question can be run without problems, if the tables have the right data. Oh, and I had to add a semi-colon too:

```sql
WITH cells AS (
  SELECT 1 cell_id, 3 region 
)
, calls AS(
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() datetime, CURRENT_DATE() date, 2 msisdn, 1 location_id
)


SELECT date(calls.datetime) AS date,
  cells.region AS region,
  COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn) AS count
FROM calls
INNER JOIN cells
    ON calls.location_id = cells.cell_id
WHERE date >= '2020-02-01'
      AND date <= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Just simply reference `date(calls.datetime)` directly as in example below

```
CREATE TABLE count_unique_subscribers_per_region_per_day AS (
    SELECT DATE(calls.datetime) AS date,
        cells.region AS region
        COUNT(DISTINCT msisdn) AS count
    FROM calls
    INNER JOIN cells
        ON calls.location_id = cells.cell_id
    WHERE DATE(calls.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
    GROUP BY 1, 2

);
```